# Load data from database and set it as global variables in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, variables, global

I have some config values in a database table that will be modified frecuently for my app.

I need to load it on every controller and set the data as variables for using them in all the application (controllers,services,twig templates, etc).

I am newbie with Symfony and i haven't find any method for creating a 'hook' which makes it.

The only thing i have thought is to save all variables in a session, but i suppose that this wouldn't be the best option.

What can i do?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Write a service that loads the data from the database in the constructor and stores it as a property inside the service-class. For twig you could write a custom Twig function.

Comment: @Frankbeen how can we confirm this service object is present before any other callables/objects?

Comment: @deeznutz - By using a kernel listener and adjusting the priority.  However, making lots of global variables is a bad idea regardless of the implementation.

Comment: yes that would do the trick, but what according to you would be the best solution to this?

Comment: The best solution is to not use globals.  I would have to look at the actual use case to determine a custom solution.